# Show that $\Phi_{p^n}(X)=\Phi_p(X^{p^{n-1}})$ with $p$ prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

How to show that $\Phi_{p^n}(X)=\Phi_p(X^{p^{n-1}})$ with $p$ prime where $\Phi_n(X)$ is the cyclotomic polynomial define by
$$\Phi_n(X)=\prod_{\underset{\gcd(k,n)=1}{k=1}}^n(X-e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{n}}).$$

I have shown already that
$$X^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(X)$$
and that 
$$\Phi_p(X)=\prod_{k=1}^p(X-e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{p}})$$

but I'm not able to conclude that
 $\Phi_{p^n}(X)=\Phi_p(X^{p^{n-1}})$ with $p$ prime.